# How to fix Xdebug 2 breakpoint not stopping in PHP 7 version

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

If I make the PHP version `php:8.1-fpm` via the Dockerfile while all the settings are the same, and I delete the tokenizer, gd libraries that are incompatible with PHP 8, and the version 2.9.8 in the Xdebug installation section from the dockerfile, Xdebug works. But when the tokenizer and gd library I use are upgraded to PHP 8, it gives an error. What should I do?

Dockerfile: (it works this way, but in this way, I cannot install the gd and tokenizer libraries because PHP 8 does not support them.)

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/
COPY composer*.json /var/www/
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install libzip-dev -y
RUN apt-get install zip unzip -y
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libgd-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# MongoDB Driver
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
#RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install ctype
RUN docker-php-ext-install fileinfo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install fileinfo
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Add user 
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

USER www
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

php.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="vscode"
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  xxx:
    build:
      context: ./php
    container_name: xxx
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    depends_on:
      - xxx_db
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ./php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      PLATFORM_STAGE: ${PLATFORM_STAGE}
    networks:
      - xxx-network
  xxx_nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: xxx_ngnix
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "91:91"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - xxx-network
  xxx_db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: xxx_db
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    tty: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      LANG: C.UTF-8
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - xxx_dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/conf.d/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - xxx-network
    

#Docker Networks
networks:
  xxx-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  xxx_dbdata:
    driver: local
```

The codes and PHP version I used while installing the tokenizer and gd libraries:

```
FROM php:7.3.33-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install tokenizer
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr
```

Comment: "it gives an error" — but then you don't say what that error is, which means nobody can help you.

Comment: It doesn't give an error, it just doesn't stop at breakpoint.

Comment: 1) **Enable Xdebug log**, try to debug and see what it has to say. That's the starting point. It may give an answer straight away (if you know what to read). Maybe it's not making a connection to VSCode at all... 2) You have `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal` -- that's for Xdebug **v3**. At the same time for Xdebug **v2** you have `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`. They are different, right?..

Comment: Thanks it worked. I removed "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal". I edited xdebug.remote_host=localhost to xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal and it worked.

Comment: *"I removed "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal"..."* Sounds like you have stopped half way. I mean: if you are removing `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal` then you can also remove other Xdebug v3 options (that do nothing in v2)...

Comment: Can you share the v3 commands you see here? I'm asking to delete.

Comment: @Furkan Check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide for v2 to v3 upgrade guide (the param names and what to use instead). V3 params in your case are: `xdebug.mode`, `xdebug.start_with_request`, `xdebug.client_host`. The ones that start with `remote_` are v2 only. The `idekey` one is used in both. If you check the Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output (or `php -i` in console) when Xdebug v3 is installed, it will mark all v2 only params with deprecation notice (for an example check such output in https://stackoverflow.com/q/75905652/783119 )