# PhpStorm: Port 9,000 specified in settings is busy

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, port, xdebug

I installed PhpStorm (latest version) and XAMPP 8.0.25, furthermore xdebug 3.2.1-8.0 on Windows 10.

When I try to debug, I get

"Port 9,000 specified in settings is busy. Port 55,464 is free and can be used by Xdebug. Please update php.ini with xdebug.remote_port/xdebug.client_port=55464"

Copying this to the `php.ini` and then restarting the Apache does nothing. The same message (with a different random port instead of 55464) appears.

What am I missing? Is there anything else to restart or adapt?

EDIT:

php.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.remote_port/xdebug.client_port=55422
```

EDIT2:

Same error with:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.client_port=57161
```

[image]

Output of `./php -i` regarding xdebug:

```
xdebug

__   __   _      _
\ \ / /  | |    | |
 \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _
  > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
 / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
/_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
                              __/ |
                             |___/

Version => 3.2.1
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

             Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                            Optional Features
Compressed File Support => yes (gzip)
Clock Source => GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime
'xdebug://gateway' pseudo-host support => no
'xdebug://nameserver' pseudo-host support => no
Systemd Private Temp Directory => not enabled

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key =>

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR => HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR
xdebug.client_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port => 57161 => 57161
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.output_dir => C:\Windows\Temp => C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.use_compression => 1 => 1
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Comment: What exactly did you add to your PHP.INI?   Just a line like `xdebug.client_port=55464` should do, see: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#:~:text=integer-,xdebug.client_port,-%3D%209003%20%23

Comment: @Luuk See my configuration above.

Comment: Never use `/` before the equal sign, so use `xdebug.client_port=55422`, and not `xdebug.remote_port/xdebug.client_port=55422`, see the docs I linked earlier.

Comment: @Luuk I used `xdebug.client_port=57161` and restartet the Apache, same error.

Comment: 1) Show your PhpStorm config, the places where you are setting up the Xdebug port. 2) Show your live Xdebug config (`xdebug_info()` output) -- your php.ini with `/` is ... what is that? 3) See what process uses that TCP 9000 port (or whatever other port you are trying to use). Use `netstat` or similar app for that (something like `netstat -abn` and then look for that port.

Comment: @LazyOne Added PhpStorm-Config. Where can I run this `xdebug_info()` command?

Comment: Regarding the port: `TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN
 [ipqservice.exe]`

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, found the xdebug info.

Comment: Use just 1 port in PhpStorm Xdebug, not need to list all of them that you have ever tried. The TCP 9000 port is used by `ipqservice.exe` (whatever that is) so you cannot use it with Xdebug. PhpStorm will try to use the first port in a list when you click on "Debug" button. Just use `9003` that Xdebug v3 uses by default (in PhpStorm and in php.ini). If it is also busy (check in advance with netstat) then use your current `57161`.

Comment: And just in case: It's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (PhpStorm in our case) on Xdebug port. It's NOT Apache or Xdebug that listens on it.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks! The reason was probably that PhpStorm automatically added all newly generated random ports to the xdebug list. When I cleared that list and only added the port I needed everything was alright.

Comment: Great! Now post it as an answer with your final solution (what steps you took to resolve it). This will help other users in a similar situation (and accepted answer will make it more visible / show that there is a solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was apparently that the automatic problem resolution of PhpStorm added the new ports to the list in the xdebug configuration instead of just replacing the existing (not working) ports.

After I removed all unnecessary ports in the xdebug configuration, it worked.

Thanks to @LazyOne who led me there.